# Using LDCT to solve an integral

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to prove that the function

$\varphi(x)= \int_0^\infty \frac{ t^{x-1} }{1+t} dt$

is continuous for any $0<x<1$.

I guess I have to use LDCT, and show something like

$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t^{\alpha}(1+t)} dt < \infty$,

for any $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

Any ideas on how to solve the question, or at least on how to show that the later integral is indeed convergent.

Comment: Are you sure the denominator is supposed to be $1-t$? The integral does not converge for any $x$ because of behavior near $t=1$.

Comment: It's $1+t$, I put minus by mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\phi (x)$ does not exist for any  $x$.

Perhaps, the denominator is supposed to be $1+t$. In that case we can prove continuity of $\phi$ as follows:

Let $x_n \to x \in (0,1)$. Then, for $t \geq 1$ and $n$ sufficiently large we have  $|\frac {t^{x_n-1}} {1+t}|\leq \frac {t^{(x-1)}/2} {t+1}$ which is integrable in $(1,\infty)$. For $t <1$ and $n$ sufficiently large we have $|\frac {t^{x_n-1}} {1+t}|\leq \frac {t^{x/2-1}} {t+1}$ which is integrable on $(0,1)$. Now apply DCT to each of the intervals $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, I meant $1+t$

Comment: But how can you show that $\frac{t^{x-1}/2}{t+1}$ and $\frac{t^{x/2-1}{t+1}$ are integrable on their domains?

Comment: @F.H.A The first one is $\leq \frac  1 {t^{\frac {3-x} 2}}$  and $\frac {3-x} 2 >1$. The second one is $\leq t^{x/2}$.